# Majority-driven manipulations of integer vectors

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

**Motivation.** Recently I was watching two people play a game that involved arranging sticks in a number of heaps and moving them around in certain allowed ways that I think I was able to infer from observation. (They told me the name of the game in their language, but I can't remember it.)

**Problem.** Let $\mathbb{N}_0$ denote the set of non-negative integers and let $n\geq 4$ be an integer. For $a,b\in\mathbb{N}_0^n$ say that $b$ *arises from a majority move* from $a$ if

1. $\sum a_i =\sum b_i$, and
2. $|\{i: b_i > a_i\}| > |\{i: b_i < a_i\}|$. (This second condition motivates the "majority" part of nomenclature).

Let $\bf{1}_n$ be the member of $\mathbb{N}_0^n$ in which all entries are $1$. Let $S_n$ be the set of members of $\mathbb{N}_0^n$ that arise from some sequence of majority moves from ${\bf 1}_n$. Let $M_n$ be the maximal value of any entry of any member of $S_n$.

What is the value of $M_n$? Do we have $\lim M_n/n = 1$? (Correct answers to either question will be accepted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M_n$=1 and so $\lim M_n/n=0\ne 1$.

(We assume your definitions mean that $\bf 1_\bf n\in {\it S_n}$.)

We claim that $S_n=\{\bf 1_\bf n\}$.

To derive a contradiction, let $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)\in S_n\setminus\{\bf 1_\bf n\}$. WLOG, it is obtained by a majority move from $\bf 1_\bf n$.  Also, WLOG $\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\dots\ge\lambda_l\ge2$, $\lambda_{l+1}=\dots=\lambda_{l+k}=1$, and $\lambda_{k+l+1}=\dots=\lambda_n=0$.  Then $0\le k<n$, so either $\lambda_1\ge2$ or $\lambda_n=0$.  If $\lambda_1\le1$, then $\lambda_1=1$ (since $\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_n=n\ge4$); but then $\lambda_n=0$, implying that $|\{i:\lambda_i>1\}|=0$ and $|\{i:\lambda_i<1\}|\ge1$, a contradiction.  Thus $\lambda_1\ge2$.

If $\lambda_i\ge3$ for some $i\ge2$, then let $c\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ be the largest such $i$, so $(\lambda_1+1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_{c-1},\lambda_c-1,\lambda_{c+1},\dots,\lambda_n)\in S_n$ and is obtained by a majority move from $\bf 1_\bf n$.  Thus, WLOG, $\lambda_2=\dots=\lambda_l=2$.

Now $l>n-(k+l)$, so $l>n-k-l$ and hence $2l>n-k$.

But $\lambda_1=n-2(l-1)-k\ge2$, so $2\le n-2l+2-k\implies 0\le n-2l-k\implies 2l\le n-k$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\kn}{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor}$
$\newcommand{\mn}{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor}$
(It is assumed in this answer that the entries of the members of $S_n$ are nonnegative real numbers, rather than nonnegative integers -- otherwise, as shown at the end of this answer, the set $S_n$ is empty.)
Take any natural $n\ge3$. Let $M_n$ be the supremum of all entries of all members of $S_n$. Then $$M_n=k_n:=\kn,$$ and this supremum is not attained.

Indeed, take any $(b_1,\dots,b_n)\in S_n$. Without loss of generality, 
there exists nonnegative integers $k$ and $m$ such that 
$$k>m,\quad k+m\le n,\tag{1}$$
$b_1\ge\dots\ge b_k>1$ for $i=1,\dots,k$,

$b_i<1$ for $i=k+1,\dots,k+m$,

$b_i=1$ for $i=k+m+1,\dots,n$.

So, 
$$m\le\min(k-1,n-k)\le\mn
$$
and 
$$k+m=n-\sum_{i=k+m+1}^n b_i\ge\sum_{i=1}^k b_i\ge b_1+(k-1)b_k\ge b_1+k-1, \tag{2}
$$
and the latter inequality is strict if $k>1$. So, $b_1\le m+1=0+1=1<\kn$ (for $n\ge3$) if $k=1$ (and hence $m=0$), and $b_1< m+1\le\kn$ if $k>1$. So,
$M_n\le\kn=k_n$, and the value $\kn$ is not attained.

On the other hand, take any $h\in(0,1)$, and let 
$$b_1=k_n-h,\quad b_2=\cdots=b_{k_n}=\frac{n-b_1}{k-1},\quad
b_{k_n+1}=\cdots=b_n=0. 
$$
Then $(b_1,\dots,b_n)\in S_n$, and $b_1$ can be made however close to $k_n=\kn$ by making $h$ small enough. This completes the proof.

---

(If the entries of the members of $S_n$ are nonnegative integers, then for any $(b_1,\dots,b_n)\in S_n$ we have $b_i\ge2$ for $i=1,\dots,k$. So, (2) implies $k+m\ge\sum_{i=1}^k b_i\ge2k$, which contradicts the first inequality in (1). This shows that $S_n$ is empty, if the entries of the members of $S_n$ are nonnegative integers.)